# making scripts for specific output from the mysql slow log

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to select word from the file and copy the others line till next #.

Means I have mysql slow query like below. from it I want to select current date time query and till the next # .

Please guide for the same.

```
# Time: **161205 10:27:39**
# localhost []
# Query_time: 5.517501  Lock_time: 0.034388 Rows_sent: 50  Rows_examined: 27061434
SET timestamp=1480913859;
SELECT   ,NULL,NULL,(SELECT
                    GROUP_CONCAT(project_master_name)
                FROM
                    project_inquiry_detail pid,project_master pm
                WHERE
                order by T.InquiryDate desc , TL.rowid desc limit 0,50;
**# Time: 161205 14:53:50**
```

Comment: this is too broad. What have you tried? please provide a [mcve]

Comment: It's also a good idea to mention why you want to do this. You might be reinventing the wheel. Maybe you're looking for what pt-query-digest does from the percona tools?

Comment: @fedorqui I tried grep, awk and sed command but not getting the expected output

Comment: @fancyPants I am making a script that when slow query logged into the mysql-slow query log in server its e-mail to me.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
sed -n -r -e  '/^SELECT /p; /^(SELECT |#)/!{p};' mysql.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
sed -n -r '/^SELECT/,/^#/p' slow.log
```

The logic is simply "don't print anything unless told so" (the `-n` switch) and print only lines between (and including) a `SELECT` at the beginning and a `#` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: thanks @fancyPants now I want to add one more pattern like sed -n -r -e '/161205/,/^#/,/use/p' /tmp/log   but its gives the error  sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown command: `,'

Comment: Well, the syntax is like `/from/,/to/command (like p for print)`. So you have too much parameters in there. What is your sed script supposed to do?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. Feel free to accept my answer :)